# How to update and avoid "sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release"

Tags: java, sun

I have a piece of code I am upgrading that has the following...

```
// TODO: Handler needs replaced
url = new URL(null, clientUrl, new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler());
```

But this throws a warning with...

> [WARNING] /....java:[91,74] sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release

What is the proper pattern for replacing this?

Comment: I think the proper pattern to replace this is to just use `url = new URL(null, clientUrl);` which lets the URL class select the correct `URLStreamHandler` (which currently is a `sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler` if the `clientUrl` is an https-URL). I think you should only pass a `URLStreamHandler` if you wrote one yourself.

Comment: @ThomasKläger I know you can do it that way but I have an existing project that is explicit and just removing the handler does not seem to work. Is there a new handler I can add explicitly instead of letting it select? Thank you

Comment: I am now facing the same issue with JDK17. Is there a solution to resolve it?